# Error on installing Orion from local tgz file with helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, fiware-orion, helm3

I am trying to install Orion. I used "helm install my-orion-ld openshift/orion-ld --version 1.0.3" but I get this error :

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download "openshift/orion-ld" at version "1.0.3"

Also when I am trying to install it through local tgz file that has been provided I get the this error :

Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

I searched for the solution and with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066604/error-kubernetes-cluster-unreachable-get-http-localhost8080-versiontimeou) I created config file in the .kobe folder in home directory but I still couldn't manage to install this chart.
I guess there is something wrong with my Helm chart installation. But when I run "helm version" command I see the correct output that seems helm is working correctly :

"version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.9.0", GitCommit:"7ceeda6c585217a19a1131663d8cd1f7d641b2a7", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.17.5"}"

Comment: I have some questions. Is your cluster up? Are you able to see the nodes by `kubectl get nodes`? Before the `helm install`, did you run `helm repo update`? If so, are you able to see the chart by `helm search`?

Comment: The result of kubectl get nodes is: 
"The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"
I didn't run "helm repo update", so I did it again and then tried to install with "helm install" but same error persist. 
the output of "helm search repo orion" is : 
openshift/fiware-orion-ld       1.0.3           1.0.1           A Helm chart for running the fiware orion-ld co..

Comment: By the way, I also got these warnings when I tried "helm search" :
"WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config"

Comment: now the result of kubectl get nodes is : "
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   22h   v1.23.3"
but I still get this error : "WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download "openshift/orion-ld" at version "1.0.3""