# Using helm and a Kubernetes Cluster with Microk8s on one or two local physical Ubuntu server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, microk8s, on-premises-instances

I installed Microk8s on a local physical Ubuntu 20-04 server (without a GUI):

```
 microk8s status --wait-ready
microk8s is running
high-availability: no
  datastore master nodes: 127.0.0.1:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    ha-cluster           # Configure high availability on the current node
    helm                 # Helm 2 - the package manager for Kubernetes
  disabled:
```

When I try to install something with helm it says:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

What configuration has to be done to use the MicroK8s Kubernetes cluster for helm installations?
Do I have to enable more MicroK8s services for that?
Can I run a Kubernetes cluster on one or two single local physical Ubuntu server with MicroK8s?

Comment: Did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914420/why-tiller-connect-to-localhost-8080-for-kubernetes-api/59547001#59547001)?

Answer (score 4):

Searching for solution for your issue, I have found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914420/why-tiller-connect-to-localhost-8080-for-kubernetes-api/59547001#59547001). Try to run:

```yaml
[microk8s] kubectl config view --raw > ~/.kube/config
```

---

Helm interacts directly with the Kubernetes API server so it needs to be able to connect to a Kubernetes cluster. Helms reads the same configuration files used by `kubectl` to do it automatically.

Based on *Learning Helm* by O'Reilly Media:

> Helm will try to find this information by reading the environment variable $KUBECONFIG. If that is not set, it will look in the same default locations that `kubectl` looks in.

---

See also:

- [This discussion about similar issue on Github](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3460)
- [This similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066604/error-kubernetes-cluster-unreachable-get-http-localhost8080-versiontimeou)